# Get custom title marker information google maps

Tags: android, maps

Hi I´m working with google maps and I create a custom title on the markers that I have, I need to know when a marker is selected how do I get the info on the title, becouse I need to open a fragment with that info, letme paste you the code I got:

```
 @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map =googleMap;
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);


        for (Taxi taxi : taxis) {
            u= taxi.getUbicacionActual();
            LatLng ubicacion= new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(u.getLatitud()), Double.parseDouble(u.getLongitud()));


            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ubicacion,15));

            MarkerOptions punto= new MarkerOptions().position(ubicacion);
            map.addMarker(punto);

            map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_title, null);


                    TextView info1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info1);
                    TextView info2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info2);
                    TextView info3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info3);

                    info1.setText("Fecha: " + u.getFecha());
                    info3.setText("Longitud: " + u.getLongitud().toString());

                    info2.setText("Ubicacion: "+obtenerDireccion(u.getLatitud(),u.getLongitud()));

                    return v;
                }
            });


        }
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                Fragment fragmento;
                fragmento = new HistorialFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_principal, fragmento)
                        .commit();


            }
        });
```

On the method OnInfoWindowClickListener where I called the new fragment I need to send the info from the custom title, could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

Add your `setOnInfoWindowClickListener` inside `getInfoContents(Marker marker)` method:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_title, null);


            final TextView info1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info1);
            TextView info2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info2);
            TextView info3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info3);

            info1.setText("Fecha: " + u.getFecha());
            info3.setText("Longitud: " + u.getLongitud().toString());

            info2.setText("Ubicacion: "+obtenerDireccion(u.getLatitud(),u.getLongitud()));

            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
                {
                    Fragment fragmento;
                    fragmento = new HistorialFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("title",info1.getText().toString());
                    fragmento.setArguments(bundle);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.content_principal, fragmento)
                            .commit();
                }
            });

            return v;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the title of the `Marker` doing

```
MarkerOptions punto= new MarkerOptions()
    .position(ubicacion)
    .title("Fecha: " + u.getFecha()); // set the marker title
map.addMarker(punto);
```

You can retrieve it on the `onInfoWindowClick` method doing:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        String title = marker.getTitle(); // Retrieve the title
    }
});
```

Comment: no I didnt, I create a custom windows with 3 textfields, and I need the info of one of them, If you check in the code I need the info form:info1.setText("Fecha: " + u.getFecha());

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can still set the marker's title and use it on your `onInfoWindowClick`

Comment: but the marker info it´s created on the method: public View getInfoContents(Marker marker), im not using the .title, becouse I have an custom windows title view.