# Kotlin & Firebase : Display different data in the bottom sheet according to the map marker that is clicked

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Kotlin. I have a map that displays different markers from the data present in Firebase (longitude, latitude).
Everything works perfectly on this side.

But I would now like to display the rest of the Firebase data in a Bottomsheet when I click on a marker.
To do so, I created a bottom sheet that is displayed when I click on a marker on the map (with setOnMarkerClickListener).
But now, I don't know how to display the data according to the marker that is clicked.

**This is my database named "Mission".**

[image]

**This is the bottom sheet displayed when I click on a marker. It works perfectly.**

[image]

**Here is the code of the map.**

```
package com.example.givenaskv1.fragment

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.airbnb.lottie.model.Marker
import com.example.givenaskv1.Map.BottomsheetMissionMap
import com.example.givenaskv1.R
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_map.*

private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap

class MapFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {
    
    private lateinit var dbref : DatabaseReference
    var marker: Marker? = null
    
    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        map_view.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        map_view.onResume()
        map_view.getMapAsync(this)
        
    }
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        mMap = googleMap!!
        // GOES UP TO 21
        val zoomLevel = 14.0f 
        // MARKER FROM DATABASE
        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Mission")
        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (missionSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val lat: String = missionSnapshot.child("latitude").value.toString()
                        val lng: String = missionSnapshot.child("longitude").value.toString()
                        val latitude = lat.toDouble()
                        val longitude = lng.toDouble()
                        val loc = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
                        val idMission = missionSnapshot.child("postid").value.toString()
                        googleMap.addMarker(
                            MarkerOptions().position(loc)
                                .title(idMission).icon(
                                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinroll))

                        )}
                }
            }
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val paris = LatLng(48.82, 2.28)

        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(paris).title("Bienvenue à Paris").icon(
            BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinroll)))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(paris))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(paris, zoomLevel));

        // OPEN BOTTOMSHEET WHEN CLICKED
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
            val bottomSheet = BottomsheetMissionMap()
            bottomSheet.show(requireFragmentManager(), "BottomSheet")
            false
        })

    }
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)
    }
}
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I have no error.
But I don't know how to display different text in TextView in the bottomsheet depending on the maker clicked on the map.
Each marker indicates a different person in Firebase.
Being two different fragments I cannot link the marker of the map to the 3 TextView of the bottomsheet.
I searched but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, your marker title is actually the key of the object that you are displaying. Since you already have the key, on a marker click, [add the title to a Bundle object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096643/get-custom-title-marker-information-google-maps), so it can be used in the second activity.

In the second activity, get the String representation of the title, and use it in a reference that points exactly to the key that is stored in the Bundle. Make a new database call and get the corresponding data so it can be displayed in your view. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

Please check the lines commented as `/* ==== UPDATED CODE ==== */`

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        mMap = googleMap!!
        // GOES UP TO 21
        val zoomLevel = 14.0f
        // MARKER FROM DATABASE
        dbref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Mission")
        dbref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (missionSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val lat: String = missionSnapshot.child("latitude").value.toString()
                        val lng: String = missionSnapshot.child("longitude").value.toString()
                        val latitude = lat.toDouble()
                        val longitude = lng.toDouble()
                        val loc = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
                        val idMission = missionSnapshot.child("postid").value.toString()
                        
                        /* ==== UPDATED CODE ==== */
                        val mMarker = googleMap.addMarker(
                            MarkerOptions().position(loc)
                                .title(idMission).icon(
                                    BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinroll)
                                )
                        )

                        /* ==== UPDATED CODE ==== */
                        mMarker?.tag = idMission as String? // or any other desired id 
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val paris = LatLng(48.82, 2.28)

        mMap.addMarker(
            MarkerOptions().position(paris).title("Bienvenue à Paris").icon(
                BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pinroll)
            )
        )
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(paris))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(paris, zoomLevel));

        // OPEN BOTTOMSHEET WHEN CLICKED
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

            /* ==== UPDATED CODE ==== */
            val id = it.tag as String?
            if (!id.isNullOrEmpty() && id == /* COMPARE WITH YOUR ID */) {
                // if true, fetch data here for bottom sheet
            } else {
                // do something else here
            } 
            
            false
        })

    }
```